# Is Primer compatible with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

I’m trying to switch to the [Primer design system](https://primer.style/), and I’m using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) right now. Is it safe to switch without actually changing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different CSS frameworks have different syntaxes, which is also why Bootstrap's is a lot different than Primer's. For example, a progress bar in Primer looks like this:

```html
<span class="Progress">
  <span class="bg-blue" style="width: 50%;"></span>
</span>
```

and the same thing in Bootstrap would be:

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe.

Always save a copy of your files before switching to the Primer design system you want to use!